# Does getTime return a day-month-year value?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, date

I thought

```html
<input type="date">
```

would return Day-Month-Year. I am attempting to calculate the difference in days from the above input. Am I overthinking this?

```js
function combinedDate() {
  (getDate(), getMonth(), getFullYear())
};

function totalDaysUpdateTotals() {
  var difference_In_Days = fday.combinedDate() - sday.combinedDate();
  let lsatotal = difference_In_Days.value * tlsa.value;
  dlsa.innerHTML = `Total LSA Days${difference_In_Days}`;
  tlsa.innerHTML = `Total LSA £${lsatotal}`;
}
```

```html
<div id="lsacalc">
  <label for="sday"> First Day of Entitlement </label>
  <input type="date" id="sday" name="sday">
  <br><hr>
  <label for="fday"> Last Day of Entitlement </label>
  <input type="date" id="fdayf" name="fday">
  <br><hr>
  <label for="rlsa"> LSA Level </label>
  <input type="text" id="rlsa" name="rlsa" Value="1">
   <br>
  <hr>
  <button onclick="totalDaysUpdateTotals;">Submit</button>
  <br>
  <hr>
  <div class="dlsa" id="tlsa"></div>
  <div class="tlsa" id="tlsa"></div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Those functions are methods of a `Date` object, they're not top-level functions.

Comment: Is your `<form>` missing its opening tag, or is it just left out of the snippet?

Comment: just left out the snippet as I used document.forms

Comment: See [*How do I get the number of days between two dates in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript?r=SearchResults&s=1|367.2367)

Answer (score 1):

You can't combine multiple methods like that.

If you want to calculate the difference in days, get the difference in milliseconds by calling the `getTime()` method, then divide by the number of milliseconds in a day (86400000).

You also don't use `.value` to access a variable's value, that's just for getting the value of an input element.

```js
function totalDaysUpdateTotals() {
  var fday = new Date(document.getElementById("fday").value);
  var sday = new Date(document.getElementById("sday").value);
  var difference_In_Days = Math.floor((fday.getTime() - sday.getTime())/86400000);
  let lsatotal = difference_In_Days * tlsa.value;
  dlsa.innerHTML = `Total LSA Days${difference_In_Days}`;
  tlsa.innerHTML = `Total LSA £${lsatotal}`;
}
```